# Just started learning Kali Linux 3 weeks ago need help with maybe a hex dump?

Tags: kali-linux, hexdump, xxd

For an assignment I was given this problem:

> What has 8 faces and cannot see?

followed by this character set:

```
412068657861676f6e616c20707269736d21204f6b2c207468617420776173206e6f742066756e6e792e20416e79776179732c206865726520697320796f757220666c61673a0a46537b65696768745f657965735f776f756c645f62655f615f626c696e645f7370696465725f3236313446397d
```

One of the hints I was given was to identify the character set first. So I was just wondering if anyone can help me identify this set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The riddle is a plain hexdump, you can reverse it with `xxd -r -p`:

```
$ echo 412068657861676f6e616c20707269736d21204f6b2c207468617420776173206e6f742066756e6e792e20416e79776179732c206865726520697320796f757220666c61673a0a46537b65696768745f657965735f776f756c645f62655f615f626c696e645f7370696465725f3236313446397d | xxd -r -p
A hexagonal prism! Ok, that was not funny. Anyways, here is your flag:
FS{eight_eyes_would_be_a_blind_spider_2614F9}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I didn't see the -p in my help menu.  Would that be the same as the -ps?  Instead of using echo I made a file out of the text and I kept using different combinations of the xxd command.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: Yes, `-p` is the same as `-ps`. The help summary is pretty short, have a look at the manpage (`man xxd`) instead.